# How to do an API call in React using a users Input ? (thumnail rendering too soon)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

"Cannot read property 'thumnail' of undefined"!

The aim of the below code is to take a users input (the name of a book) then pass that information to the API call. API call is then set in state. Then information in the render form is appended to the DOM.

For some reason the above error appears for the last prop "photo". I believe the reason is due to render running before the API call is made, although I am not certain. All other props appear on the page except for the photo prop.

As a beginner to software I would appreciate help with:

- The above problem
- should I be implementing ComponentDidMount and how?

I have tried rendering the prop conditionally although I am not sure if I did this correctly.

```
  state = {
    searchedBook: "",
    responseBook: false
  };

...

 photo={this.state.responseBook ? this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumnail : null}
```

This stopped the error but did not render the photo to the page.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import BookCard from "./components/BookCard";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchedBook: "",
    responseBook: ""
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchedBook: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${
      this.state.searchedBook
    }`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          searchedBook: "",
          responseBook: data.items[0].volumeInfo
        })
      )
      .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          state={this.state}
        />

        <BookCard
          title={this.state.responseBook.title}
          subTitle={this.state.responseBook.subtitle}
          averageRating={this.state.responseBook.averageRating}
          photo={this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumnail}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

BookCard.js

```
import React from "react";

const BookCard = props => {
  return (
    <div className="book-card--container">
      <img src={props.photo} alt="book cover" className="book-card--img" />
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="book-card--h1">{props.title}</h1>
        <h2 className="book-card--h2">{props.subTitle}</h2>
        <span className="book-card--span">
          {props.averageRating} out of 5 stars
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookCard;
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";

const Form = props => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <input value={props.state.searchedBook} onChange={props.onChange} />
      <button>Search!</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: I think... typo. `photo={this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumnail}` => `photo={this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumbnail}`

Comment: @zynkn Thanks for the comment but unfortunately its not a typo

Answer (score 1):

[image]

They are returning like this.

```
photo={this.state.responseBook ? this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumnail : null}
```

and you wrote `thumnail` without `b`.

you should replace all `thumnail` to `thumbnail`.

Comment: I changed it but didn't implement the following code `photo={this.state.responseBook ? this.state.responseBook.imageLinks.thumbnail : null}` so thought it still wasn't working. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: @NewTech did you check the `<BookCard />` properties? There is another `thumnail`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this.state.responseBook.imageLinks` is `undefined`.

You could try logging your variable in the console and looking at it's variables: `console.log(this.state.responseBook)`

Are you accessing your own API? or a public one?

Comment: If I comment out "photo" prop and add the console.log you suggest above it returns a blank line repeated blank lines as I type until I click the submit button, after which it return the object I want.

Comment: @NewTech Where did you put the `console.log`? You should put it in the function that recieves the API call, it will only print once then

Answer (score 0):

this is because in your local state you have responseBook as a Bolean value. You are trying to access properties on it like it is an object whenever it is just false. The responseBook you are trying to access is in state with the api call.

```
state = {responseBoolean: false
         responseBook: this.props.responseBook}
```

You need to change the name of the Boolean and then bring in the real responseBook object from App.js as props.